# change preview image from given images on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The below code represents the code for preview image and list of images in web page.

```
<div class="col-lg-5 text-center">
                    <img src="img/1.jpeg">  //preview image
<hr>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img onclick="imagereset()" id="1" src="img/1.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img onclick="imagereset()" id="2" src="img/2.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img onclick="imagereset()" id="3" src="img/3.jpeg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img onclick="imagereset()" id="4" src="img/4.jpeg">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Please help me to update preview image on click event of any image list using javascript function.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to post more code. and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML code to add an `id` to your preview image and pass the reference to each image to the `imagereset()` function:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 text-center">
    <img id="preview-img" src="img/1.jpeg">  <!--preview image-->
    <hr>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img onclick="imagereset(this)" id="1" src="img/1.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img onclick="imagereset(this)" id="2" src="img/2.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img onclick="imagereset(this)" id="3" src="img/3.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img onclick="imagereset(this)" id="4" src="img/4.jpeg">
    </div>
</div>
```

That way, you can simply implement the function this way:

```
function imagereset(elem) {
    var newSrc;
    switch (elem.id) {
        case "1": newSrc = ...; break;
        ...
    }
    document.getElementById("preview-img").src = newSrc;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to make preview image dynamically by checking if the image has id=1 then particular image source and so on.